# Graphql schema with nested instances of same type

Tags: graphql, faunadb

So, I am experimenting with Graphql and Fauna DB for the first time, and I need to make a query to populate a table in a Reactjs App.

The data I need to pass to the table component is an array that looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    account: '1',
    ... other fields,
    children:[
      {
        account: '1.1'
        children: [ ... ]
      }
    ]
]
```

Right now my graphql schema looks like this:

```
type Account @collection(name: "accounts") {
  name: String!
  code: String!
}

type Query {
  allAccounts: [Account!]! @index(name: "all_accounts")
  getAccount(code: String!): Account
}
```

I am not sure what would be the best way to do this. One way would be to just store all accounts at the same level, and then structure the data in the front-end (I can loop trough the results and nest the objects according to the account number). But if there is a better way to do it taking advantage of Graphql (or Fauna) I would like to try it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "circular/cyclic graphql"

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent forums topic about this.

https://forums.fauna.com/t/graphql-self-reference/2258

Here is the short answer:

You can create an intermediate “link table” yourself. Fauna creates many-to-many relationships by creating an intermediate Collection and abstracting the implementation out of the way for you. It’s more tedious to do yourself but it is possible.

Example schema:

```
type Account {
  name: String!
  code: String!
  children: [AccountLink!] @relation(name: "account_children")
  parents: [AccountLink!] @relation(name: "account_parents")
}

type AccountLink {
  parent: Account! @relation(name: "account_children")
  child: Account! @relation(name: "account_parents")
}
```